# How to dynamically create a nested Json file in angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, loops, typescript

I want to dynamically create a nested Json file in angular. 
It gets extract from another Json file.
Two nested Loops read the data. 
Json File:

```
{
"data": [
    [
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"},
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"},

    ],
    [
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"},
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
        {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"},
    ],
```

and now i want to extract that into a javascript array/map.
In the ts file.

Comment: what do you mean with nested json file. can you add more context to your question.

Comment: I got a json file that has 3 loops in it. Now i want to extract that file into javascript (into a map or an array). 
Out of this another json file should be created.

Comment: Can you add some source code?

Comment: Please add some examples to your question

Comment: edited the json code

Answer (score -1):

JSON data (i.e. a string containing serialized JSON) can be parsed straight into an object, and then used in JavaScript / TypeScript. `JSON.parse` is your method for doing this.

Complete example:

```
const json = `{
    "data": [
        [
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"},
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"}
        ],
        [
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"},
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 4, "Nr": "11", "stat": "bye"},
            {"dat": "hello", "date": 2, "Nr": "13", "stat": "bye"}
        ]
    ]
}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(json);

for (let collection of obj.data) {
    for (let item of collection) {
        console.log('Item:', item.dat, item.Nr, item.stat);
    }
}
```

## Add an Interface

You can add an interface to improve the type information and auto-completion of the parsed structure:

```
interface MyJson {
    data: { dat: string, date: number, Nr: string, stat: string }[][];
}

const obj: MyJson = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: should not use a for loop for Array manipulation. Not in this day and age anyway

Comment: @George what alternative would you prefer for the example, bearing in mind the question is really about parsing JSON, and the loops are just there to demonstrate the result.

Comment: oh yeh, i'd just remove that bit then as it's quite confusing

Comment: @George am really also not sure why a loop is not a good way to traverse an array! What other ways we have in js

Comment: filter, map, reduce and now forEach which is supported all the way down to IE 9

Comment: `.forEach` is the only one of those that is analogous to `for-of` (for-of was only added in ECMAScript 2015, so it isn't ancient history just yet). There are a few features of a `for-of` that mean you won't be eliminating it just yet too, for example you can break out of a `for-of`, which you can't do on the `array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: ah okay for-of isn't supported in Internet Explorer at all so i would strongly suggest using forEach instead. If breaking out of your code is a worry, you should look at your data structure before and maybe use a filter etc

Comment: @George - welcome to TypeScript land - `for-of` has down-level compilation based on your target ECMAScript version... so in TypeScript `for-of` works everywhere.

Comment: @Fenton Ah okay. apologies, I can't upvote your answer now without an edit. I'll upvote your comments instead :)

Comment: @George no worries - always happy to tell people how awesome TypeScript is :)